# How to dispatch touch events to parent composables in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I can't seem to find much information on touch handling in Compose.

In the specific case I'm looking at I have a list like this:

```
@Composable
fun MyListComposable(items: List<Item>) {
    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = paddingValues(listHorizontalMargin, listVerticalMargin),
    ) {
        // Init items emitted for brevity
    }

}
```

This list is contained in a parent which uses the `swipeable` modifier, something like this.

```
Card(
    modifier = Modifier.swipeable(
        state = state,
        anchors = mapOf(
            0.dp.value to DrawerState.OFFSCREEN,
            50.dp.value to DrawerState.PEEKING,
            maxHeight.value to DrawerState.EXPANDED,
        ),
        reverseDirection = true,
        thresholds = { _, _ -> FractionalThreshold(0f) },
        orientation = Orientation.Vertical
    ) {
         MyListComposable(items)
}
```

My problem is the list swallows all touches, so the swipable is never invoked. So my question is, is there a way to stop lazy column swallowing touches?

Comment: I have a semi working sample now with `.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)` and a custom `NestedScrollConnection`. Checkout the `BottomDrawerLayout` if you want to see a reliable sample. `NestedScrollConnection` essentially lets a parent hook into nested scrolls and change/consume/ignore the scroll delta.

Comment: I am also struggling with similar problem. Have you found any solution?